# finished with error - code: -1009 when internet there is no connection

Tags: swift, alamofire, facebook-ios-sdk, google-ios-vision

We are using Google SDKs like SignIn,maps and Analytics. 
Facebook SDK for signIn. 
Alamofire and ObjectMapper for Networking and JSON parsing.
Realm for DB.

When there is no internet connection I am getting following error on console. I have verified these are not our App Errors .

> TIC TCP Conn Failed [45:0x1c8178240]: 1:50 Err(50) Task
>   <293866EE-82E6-4740-AEAF-83A1BB11E98A>.<1> HTTP load failed (error
>   code: -1009 )

Can anyone explain which framework is logging this error.

Answer (score 2):

`-1009` is actually `NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet` from [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1508628-url_loading_system_error_codes/nsurlerrornotconnectedtointernet)

The log is coming from OS and you can turn it off if you set `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` environment variable to `disable`

```
Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Arguments -> Environment Variables
```